How to play a sound in Quick look extension in iOS device?
I add a Quick look extension to my app to preview my custom file type. The Kodeco.com has a good starting point. I need to play a sound in this preview view controller. I use AVAudioPlayer() like this:
class SoundPlayer {
    var logger: Monitor = Monitor(.Mecordi)
    
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    init(from soundURL: URL) {
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print("Error loading sound file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func playSound() {
        audioPlayer?.play()
    }

    func stopSound() {
        audioPlayer?.stop()
    }
}

class PreviewViewController: UIViewController, QLPreviewingController {
    var soundPlayer: SoundPlayer?

    // @IBOutlet weak var previewView: PreviewView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func playAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let audioFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sound", withExtension: "mp3")!
        self.soundPlayer = SoundPlayer(from: audioFileURL)
        self.soundPlayer?.playSound()
    }
}

It works on simulator, but on device it raise following errors:
[AQClient]              AQClient.cpp:692   Couldn't connect to com.apple.audio.AudioQueueServer; AudioQueue will not be usable

[default] AudioQueueNew is passing a serverPID of 0 to CheckRPCError!

[default] CheckRPCError: AudioQueueNew returned server mach error 0x10000003!

[default] FetchAndDeliverPendingCallbacks is passing a serverPID of 0 to CheckRPCError!

[default] AudioQueueDispose is passing a serverPID of 0 to CheckRPCError!

[default] CheckRPCError: FetchAndDeliverPendingCallbacks returned server mach error 0x10000003!

[UIKBFeedbackGenerator] <_UIKBFeedbackGenerator: 0x281e6a080>: Error, attempting to read ringer state with an invalid token.

By the way, if I use AVAudioEngine it will play the sound on both simulator and device. But I need to solve it with AVAudioPlayer().
